# String with up to 2 decimal places Android

Tags: java, android

Currently in my `strings.xml` I have

```
`<string name="price_string">My string with price: %1$s</string>`
```

The problem with this is it outputs 5, instead of 5.5. How would I format it to include up to 2 decimals?

Answer (score 4):

```
<string name="price_string">My string with price: %0.2f$s</string>`
```